# What is the syntax of angular one time binding for multiple properties in ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, one-time-binding

I have an

`ng-if="dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval === dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN"`.

What i want to do is to have one time bindings for both variables in `ng-if`. But when i try to use

`ng-if="(::dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval) === (::dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN)"`

angular throws the following error :

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary
>   expression at     column 2 of the expression
>   [(::dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval)     ===
>   (::dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN)] starting at
>   [::dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval) ===
>   (::dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN)].

What is the right way ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
ng-if="::(dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval === dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN)"
```

Comment: this way it will not work as expected, because when either of the properties becomes stable then the expression itself becomes stable(false in this case, as the second argument will be null at that time) and the watcher for the whole expression will be removed. Hence when second property becomes stable it's value will not have any effect on the whole expression result.

Comment: You can add `dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval === undefined ? undefined : dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN === undefined ? undefined : ...`

Comment: Yes, but the expression becomes too complex, i think there should be more straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

this should works fine:

```
ng-if="::dc.emailNotificationSchedule.progressInterval == dc.SkillCompletionProgressIntervals.NEVER_LOGGED_IN"
```

You don't need double colon twice

Comment: the colon only in front of the first property will have effect only on the first property i think.